# How to add kubernetes labels to the log data using promtail?

Tags: grafana-loki

We can't seem to find in promtail a way to add kubernetes labels to the log data–seems to only allow copying that data to labels, not the log data itself. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a 'correct' way, but there is a workaround:

```
      relabel_configs:
      - replacement: your_label_val
        source_labels:
        - __path__
        target_label: your_label
```

Comment: Thank you QiaoWen! 

I assumed I had formed my question in an inappropriate way or made some other mistake in the asking of it. After nearly 4 months I just assumed it was not a question worth responding to.

I sincerely appreciate your response....thanks!

I _think_ my guys found a workaround also but will check. Yours, based on my limited knowledge, looks like it should work. Four months ago we were new to all-things Prometheus---we've learned a lot in that time.